# Definition of carrier concentration $p = 0.1$?

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, material-science

When reading some literature in physics I came across expressions like:

> "Our super-high-resolution ARPES experiments reveal an insulator–superconductor transition at a critical doping level of P = 0.10"

> "Photoemission intensity plots of the S phase corresponding to carrier concentrations of 0.073, 0.073, 0.076"

Would anyone explains a bit about the definition of the carrier concentration/doping level p? I guess it's related to carrier numbers/cm^3?

Comment: There are a number of ways to quantify the doping level. Do you have a link to the place that you read this?

Comment: Are you sure, they are the same? with a doping of superconductors and a dimensionless number I would expect it to be a stochiometric thing. Carrier concentrations on the other hand should have the unit/dimension of a concentration, e.g. $\mathrm{m^{-1}}$

Comment: Here are the full texts where the sentences come from: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms3459     and     https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.1414094112

Comment: I'm not sure if they are the same, without any unit I have a hard time googling what the numbers mean.